# regular expressions missing out certain letters

Tags: php, regex

Is there a simple way to ignore/miss out certain letters. The problem is find a word that is 5 letters long but does not contain the letters b,j,m or n.

Can I simply only specify the letters I do want such as [a][c-i][k-l][o-2]? This doesn't appear very clean and I still need to specify the word needs to be 5 letters long. So I guess I need a /w and a {5} but am not sure how to combine it all. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This selects all characters except bjmn:

```
[^bjmn]{5}
```

If you want only lower case **letters** except those you listed:

```
[c-ik-lo-za]{5}
```

If you don't want 5-letter-words that are part of longer words, add word boundary checking:

```
\b[c-ik-lo-za]{5}\b
```

Comment: OP wants only `letters` except `bjmn`, not any character from what I understand.

Comment: OP also wants only words which are 5 letters long, this will also match words like 'aduou' in 'baduouwwen'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[a][c-i][k-l][o-2]`, try `[ac-ik-lo-z]{5}`, which should detect strings of five allowed letters.

EDIT: Oops, you specifically wanted **words**. Just test for word boundaries on either side, then: `\b[ac-ik-lo-z]{5}\b` - checking for spaces will make you miss a match if it's the last on a line and has a period after it, a comma after it, is in brackets, etc.

Comment: As davide mentioned too, if you care about case sensitivity, you might want to either explicitly allow or deny capital versions too, or just use a flag to make the regex case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use [^bjmn] or [^BbJjMmNn] if you also do not want the uppercase ones.

Comment: OP wants only letters except bjmn, not any character from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\W[ac-ik-lo-z]{5}\W` (this matches white space on either side of a group of five characters that don't contain the ones you were looking for.

You can combine multiple ranges into one list, as above.

Comment: Swap your \W for \b to test for word boundaries in general. For example, what if the word is the last on the line and has a period after it, or a comma?

Answer (score 0):

This requires a word to have 5 letters but not include any of the `bjmn`. This could be simplified by using letter spans like [ac-i] but those tend to get a bit confusing when trying to read.

`\b([acdefghiklopqrstuvwxyz]{5})\b`

[image]

[image]